# Solve large number of small equation systems in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a large number of small linear equation systems that I'd like to solve efficiently using numpy. Basically, given `A[:,:,:]` and `b[:,:]`, I wish to find `x[:,:]` given by `A[i,:,:].dot(x[i,:]) = b[i,:]`. So if I didn't care about speed, I could solve this as

```
for i in range(n):
    x[i,:] = np.linalg.solve(A[i,:,:],b[i,:])
```

But since this involved explicit looping in python, and since `A` typically has a shape like `(1000000,3,3)`, such a solution would be quite slow. If numpy isn't up to this, I could do this loop in fortran (i.e. using f2py), but I'd prefer to stay in python if possible.

Comment: Surely a large number of small linear equations can be assembled in a single large, sparse linear system and solved once?

Comment: Yes, they could. Would that be efficient? Do you think it would compare favorably to a loop in fortran?

Comment: Honestly, things like this are where Cython shines.  It's not exactly staying in python, but it's not straying very far, and using numpy arrays is completely seamless. It won't be as fast as fortran, but it's not slow, either.

Comment: @joferkington: So you would use Cython in a loop to build up the sparse matrix, and then solve it as a sparse system? Calling `np.linalg.solve` from a Cython loop would be unproductive, wouldn't it, as Cython wouldn't be able to remove the python overhead to that function call.

Comment: You're absolutely right that the bottleneck will be the overhead in a python function call, but I'd still try calling `np.linalg.solve` inside the loop in cython before trying the sparse solution. You can avoid a significant amount of the python overhead by using numpy's C interface if it becomes necessary.  Of course, with too much hackery it's going to be cleaner to just use fortran.  Let me see if I can cobble together an example. It may not be as fast as I'm claiming it will be...

Comment: Actually, what about `numpy.linalg.tensorsolve`? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.tensorsolve.html

Comment: @joferkington: `tensorsolve` looks very promising, but its documentation is a bit obscure. How would I call it with A (100000,3,3) and b (100000,3)? `tensorsolve(A,b)` does not work. If `tensorsolve` can be made to work for this, that would probably be just what I'm looking for, and the description of how to do so would make a fine answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess answering yourself is a bit of a faux pas, but this is the fortran solution I have a the moment, i.e. what the other solutions are effectively competing against, both in speed and brevity.

```
function pixsolve(A, b) result(x)
    implicit none
    real*8    :: A(:,:,:), b(:,:), x(size(b,1),size(b,2))
    integer*4 :: i, n, m, piv(size(b,1)), err
    n = size(A,3); m = size(A,1)
    x = b
    do i = 1, n
        call dgesv(m, 1, A(:,:,i), m, piv, x(:,i), m, err)
    end do
end function
```

This would be compiled as:

```
f2py -c -m foo{,.f90} -llapack -lblas
```

And called from python as

```
x = foo.pixsolve(A.T, b.T).T
```

(The `.T`s are needed due to a poor design choice in f2py, which both causes unnecessary copying, inefficient memory access patterns and unnatural looking fortran indexing if the `.T`s are left out.)

This also avoids a setup.py etc. I have no bone to pick with fortran (as long as strings aren't involved), but I was hoping that numpy might have something short and elegant which could do the same thing.

Comment: Mmmm that code doesn't seem to work for me. I don't know much about f2py or fortran, but this does work for me: http://pastebin.com/xDfZXKTq (basically, I need another parameter when calling dgesv, and I assume A has shape (N, 3, 3) as in your question.

Comment: @jorgeca: f2py handles the C/fortran dimension ordering poorly - its default behavior is to assume that you want it to make an expensive copy to preserve the indexing scheme rather than the actual memory layout. To avoid this, every numpy array passed to f2py must be tranposed first (this transposition does not actually cause a copy, but rather serves to prevent one). My example above assumes that you do that, i.e. that you call x = pixsolve(A.T, b.T).T from python.

Comment: You get a ~20% speed up avoiding the f2py copy. But it should be `A.transpose((1, 2, 0))` instead of `A.T` (else you're solving for the transpose of your systems).

Comment: `A.transpose((1,2,0))` would involve copying, wouldn't it? And could you elaborate more on how I would be solving the transpose of my system with `A.T`? Effectively, f2py is inserting a `.T` implicitly everywhere, and the `.T`s I'm inserting simply cancel out those.

Comment: I think it isn't making a copy (checked using `.base` and `np.may_share_memory`). The speed difference between calling pixsolve_faster with `A.T` and `A.transpose((1,2,0))` is small (5% as opposed to over 20%)

Answer (score 6):

For those coming back to read this question now, I thought I'd save others time and mention that numpy handles this using broadcasting now.

So, in numpy 1.8.0 and higher, the following can be used to solve N linear equations.

```
x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're wrong about the explicit looping being a problem.  Usually it's only the innermost loop it's worth optimizing, and I think that holds true here.  For example, we can measure the code of the overhead vs the cost of the actual computation:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10**6
A = np.random.random(size=(n, 3, 3))
b = np.random.random(size=(n, 3))
x = b*0

def f():
    for i in xrange(n):
        x[i,:] = np.linalg.solve(A[i,:,:],b[i,:])

np.linalg.pseudosolve = lambda a,b: b

def g():
    for i in xrange(n):
        x[i,:] = np.linalg.pseudosolve(A[i,:,:],b[i,:])
```

which gives me

```
In [66]: time f()
CPU times: user 54.83 s, sys: 0.12 s, total: 54.94 s
Wall time: 55.62 s

In [67]: time g()
CPU times: user 5.37 s, sys: 0.01 s, total: 5.38 s
Wall time: 5.40 s
```

IOW, it's only spending 10% of its time doing anything other than actually solving your problem.  Now, I could totally believe that `np.linalg.solve` itself is too slow for you relative to what you could get out of Fortran, and so you want to do something else.  That's probably especially true on small problems, come to think of it: IIRC I once found it faster to unroll certain small solutions by hand, although that was a while back.

But by itself, it's not true that using an explicit loop on the first index will make the overall solution quite slow.  If `np.linalg.solve` is fast enough, the loop won't change it much here.

Comment: I agree that benchmarks are important for things like this. I set up `A` and `b` with the same dimensions as in your example, and filled them with random numbers (but I added 10 to each diagonal in `A` to make the matrix positive definite). I then solved the systems first by looping in python, and then by calling fortran. The former took 36.6 s per loop, similar to what you saw. The latter took 1.29 s per loop. So that is roughly a *factor 20* difference in speed!

Comment: By "calling fortran", I assume you mean calling your `pixsolve` routine.  That is not calling `np.linalg.solve`.  As I said, it's entirely likely that `np.linalg.solve` is too slow for what you want it to do.  But it's not slow *because of the loop*.  The loop has almost no effect on the total speed.

Comment: From the documentation: "`solve` is a wrapper for the LAPACK routines `dgesv` and `zgesv`". So `np.linalg.solve` is doing exactly the same as what my fortran function is loing every iteration. The only difference is exactly the python overhead I am worried about. To prove this, I tried calling pixsolve elementwise on A[i:i+1,:,:] etc. in a python loop. The execution time was 10 seconds, so faster than `np.linalg.solve`, but still a factor 8 slower than avoiding the python loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in one go, with a (3x100000,3x100000) matrix composed of 3x3 blocks around the diagonal.

Not tested :

```
b_new = np.vstack([ b[i,:] for i in range(len(i)) ])
x_new = np.zeros(shape=(3x10000,3) )

A_new = np.zeros(shape=(3x10000,3x10000) )
n,m = A.shape
for i in range(n):
   A_new[3*i:3*(i+1),3*i:3*(i+1)] = A[i,:,:]

x = np.linalg.solve(A_new,b_new)
```

Comment: Hmm. This approach still has the python loop with n iterations, though, which is what I'm trying to avoid. But I think scipy.sparse.block_diag can construct the sparse A_new in one go.

Comment: After some testing, it seems like scipy.sparse.block_diag(A) is extremely slow, and uses huge amounts of memory.

Comment: I may be reading this incorrectly, but are you proposing that I generate and solve a dense matrix system of 300000 by 300000, a huge and heavy problem, just to avoid some python function call overhead?