# vectorising linalg.eig() in numpy

Tags: optimization, numpy, linear-algebra

I have an m*m*n numpy array (call it A) and I would like to find the eigenvalues of every submatrix `A[:,:,n]` in this array. I could do it with `linalg.eig()` in a loop with relative ease, but there really ought to be a way to vectorise this. Something like a `ufunc`, but that can process subvectors instead of individual elements. Is this possible?

Comment: On a side note, if you happen to be dealing with symmetric matrices, you can use `np.linalg.eigh`, which is significantly faster (again, for the specific, but common, case of a symmetric input--e.g. a covariance matrix).  Of course, this doesn't answer your vectorization problem (@jorgeca is correct, there's no way to vectorize this directly, and it will only be significantly faster if `m` is very small and `n` is very large).

Comment: assuming `m` is small and `n` is not, and assuming you're running it on a multicore machine, a possible way of speeding this up is to use the `multiprocessing` module: just assign several matrices to each process.

Answer (score 2):

The computation of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors can not be vectorised in the sense that there's no way in general to share work for different matrices. `np.linalg.eig` (for real input) is just a wrapper for [`dgeev`](http://www.netlib.no/netlib/lapack/double/dgeev.f), which according to the docs only accepts a single matrix per call and the computation is fairly expensive, so for matrices that are not small the overhead of a python loop will be negligible.

Though, if you're doing this for many very small matrices it can become too slow. There are [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13432129/1191119) related to this and the solution usually ends up being a compiled extension. As enigmaticPhysicist says in a comment, the idea of processing subvectors and submatrices in the same way as ufuncs would be useful in general. These are called generalised ufuncs and are already in numpy's [development version](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3220). I find it around 8 times faster for matrices of shape `(1000, 3, 3)`:

```
In [2]: np.__version__
Out[2]: '1.8.0.dev-dcf7cac'

In [3]: A = np.random.rand(1000, 3, 3)

In [4]: timeit np.linalg.eig(A)
P100 loops, best of 3: 9.65 ms per loop

In [5]: timeit [np.linalg.eig(Ai) for Ai in A]
10 loops, best of 3: 74.6 ms per loop

In [6]: a1 = np.linalg.eig(A)

In [7]: a2 = [np.linalg.eig(Ai) for Ai in A]

In [8]: all(np.allclose(a1[i][j], a2[j][i]) for j in xrange(1000) for i in xrange(2))
Out[8]: True
```

Comment: Well, it so happens that m <i>is</i> very small. (It's only 4.) Otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question. Believe me lol. I'm looking at the idea of using an eigenvalue solver more directly with C. I've got some code working and I think I can get it working as fast as I want it to be. But it seems like if ufuncs exist at all, and they do, even the idea of processing subvectors and submatrices in the same way would be useful in general.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist The behaviour you'd like (generalised `ufuncs` that process subarrays) is already in numpy's [development version](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3220), if you're willing to build and use that.

Comment: hey, that's cool, Jorge! If I get the time, I'll definitely need to have a look.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist I just updated the answer to include timings (from a plain ATLAS build).